# Prayaschitta (regret) Mantra when one breaks fasting during Shravana month?

Tags: shiva, mantras, fasting, prayaschitta

Is there any praaschitta mantra if someone by mistake breaks fasting during holy month of Shravana?

Comment: Better to explain the purpose of fasting during Shravana month.  As far as I know, there is no custom of fasting in Shravana in South India.  We are aware of fasting in Kaartika month. @The Little Naruto

Comment: @srimannarayanakv That background I don't have. But that's the tradition I have been seeing till now.

Comment: May be.  As far as I know, tradition/custom is for self regulatory purpose only.  However, bhakti drives and controls human activities in a right perspective.  Tradition/custom mixed with bhakti will elevate one to higher levels.  The purpose of tradition/custom is that much only.. @The Little Naruto